# PHP num_rows output giving unexpected results

Tags: php

I am trying the following code. Results are driving me crazy. Am I missing something silly?

```
$sql = 'SELECT id,status FROM table where id = ?';
$stm = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stm->bind_param('i', $id);
$stm->execute();
$stm->store_result();

die($stm->num_rows) // outputs nothing

$num = $stm->num_rows;
die($num) // outputs nothing

die('Records '.$num); //outputs Records 4
```

Why is this so? I want to output the number of records, but isn't working. It works only when I append a text to it.

Comment: *"I want to output the number of records"* -- use [`echo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php). Its purpose is to display values. Read the [documentation of `die()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php). It clearly explains that it displays its argument only if it is a string. And its purpose is not to display values but to terminate the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concerning the parameter in the parenthesis of `die()` and its equivalent `exit()`, the PHP manual states:

> If `status` (i.e. the parameter) is an integer, that value will be used as the exit status
>   and not printed. Exit statuses should be in the range 0 to 254, the
>   exit status 255 is reserved by PHP and shall not be used. The status 0
>   is used to terminate the program successfully.

and

> No value is returned.

So just use `echo` to get a visible output...